# Generic stack in objective-c without nsmutablearrays?

Tags: objective-c

How would you implement a generic stack without using nsmutablearrays?

Comment: What have you bothered trying/looking at so far?

Comment: The question is really: "How would YOU implement a generic stack without using nsmutablearrays?" Or would you rather someone else did all the work for you? Please show some effort.

Comment: Whats wrong with using NSMutableArray for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this I'd think:

```
@interface Stack {
     id *objects;
     int allocatedSize;
 }

 -(void) push:(id) value;
 -(id) peek;
 -(id) pop;

 @end

 @implementation Stack

  -(void) push:(id) value {
       objects = realloc(objects, ++allocatedSize * sizeof id);
       objects[allocatedSize - 1] = value;
  }

  -(id) pop
  {
        id temp = objects[--allocatedSize];
        objects = realloc(objects, allocatedSize * sizeof id);
        return temp;
  }

  -(id) peek
  {
        return objects[allocatedSize - 1];
  }

 @end
```

MAJOR NOTICE:
This code is BUGGY at the least. ARC and malloc do NOT work well with each other, so take caution to clear your memory before setting a value. Also, please add error checking, as I wrote this in mobile safari, there wasn't much time for fancy code checks.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a stack using [arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29#Array) (C arrays if you don't want to use `NSMutableArray`). But I guess this is not that much different from using an NSMutableArray.

To completely avoid arrays, you can implement the stack using [linked lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29#Linked_list).

The following code is an illustration of the linked list based stack:

```
- (void)push:(id)item
{
    Node *newHead = [[Node alloc] init];
    newHead.data = item;

    newHead.next = self.head;
    self.head = newHead;
}

- (id)pop
{
    Node *oldHead = head;
    self.head = self.head.next;
    return oldHead.data;
}
```